# Customizing the survey form in SurveyMonkey with custom variables

Tags: surveymonkey

I am currently using SurveyMonkey to send surveys to a set of colleges. The questions in the survey form are exactly the same except for the first question where I am including the college name. I am creating separate surveys for each college because of this. Is there a way to actually leverage some advanced options within SM that help me do this in a single survey link? like, having a variable placeholder or so?